# purpose of 'num_samples' in Tune of Ray package for hyperprameter optimization

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, hyperparameters, ray

I am trying to perform a hyper parameter optimization task for a LSTM (pure Tensorflow) with [Tune](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html). I followed their example on the [hyperopt](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-searchalg.html) algorithm. In the example they have used the below line inside the 'config' section.

> "num_samples": 10 if args.smoke_test else 1000,

The documenatation does not explain what this is. I am uable to determine if this is a useful piece of code or how am I supposed to alter this for my scenario.  So it will be great if I can know the meaning of this line of code.

The example hyperopt code can be found through [this link](https://github.com/ray-project/ray/blob/master/python/ray/tune/examples/hyperopt_example.py)

Comment: this is called a ternary expression - it sets the `"num_samples"` variable to 10 or 1000 depending on some other given variable. From the names I would _guess_ it samples some given data at 10 or 1000 points to create whatever it does ... you would need to look through the documentation to see for yourself. `"num_samples"` is provided as kwargs param. Maybesomewhere around here: https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-usage.html?highlight=num_samples

Answer (score 5):

You can find the parameter [in the documentation of `run_experiments`](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-usage.html?highlight=run_experiments#sampling-multiple-times).

> By default, each random variable and grid search point is sampled once. To take multiple random samples, add num_samples: N to the experiment config. If grid_search is provided as an argument, the grid will be repeated num_samples of times.

Essentially the parameter is part of the configuration and can be used to sample your data multiple times instead of only once.

Your demo code however uses `run_experiment`:

```
config = {
    "my_exp": {
        "run": "exp",
        "num_samples": 10 if args.smoke_test else 1000,
        "config": {
            "iterations": 100,
        },
        "stop": {
            "timesteps_total": 100
        },
    }
}
algo = HyperOptSearch(space, max_concurrent=4, reward_attr="neg_mean_loss")
scheduler = AsyncHyperBandScheduler(reward_attr="neg_mean_loss")
run_experiments(config, search_alg=algo, scheduler=scheduler)  # here the config is passed
```

Comment: Thanks, any idea what 'args.smoke_test' is supposed to do?

Comment: args.smoke_test is just a boolean we use to make running tests easy. You can simply consider the line to basically be `"num_samples": 10`.

Comment: @Sul `10 if args.smoke_test else 1000,` is a ternary expression that says "if `args.smoke_test` is true use `10` else `1000` - think of it like a "small" and a "big" testingscenario based on some input. Hint: if you put a @ before a username it auto_completes it for you if this person was inside this answer/qeustion and _more importantly_ the person gets a message that someone sain something - somehow your comment eluded me :)

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation:

> num_samples (int) – Number of times to sample from the hyperparameter
>   space. Defaults to 1. If grid_search is provided as an argument, the
>   grid will be repeated num_samples of times.

Substitue of repeat:

> repeat (int) – Deprecated  and  will  be  removed  in  future 
>   versions  of  Ray. Use num_samples instead

Usage:

```
"num_samples": 10

num_samples=10

class ray.tune.Experiment(name,run,stop=None,config=None,trial_resources=None,
repeat=1,num_samples=1,local_dir=None,upload_dir=None,checkpoint_freq=0,
checkpoint_at_end=False,max_failures=3,restore=None)
```